# how can I implement sql server char calculation to my sql server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i am getting result B000 by running below query in sql server

```
select (char(1000 / 1000 % 26 + 65) + 
    char(1000 / 100 % 10 + 48) + 
    char(1000 / 10 % 10 + 48) + 
    char(1000 % 10 + 48)) ;
```

while i am getting 0 when i am running same query in my sql

```
 select (char(1000 / 1000 % 26 + 65) + 
    char(1000 / 100 % 10 + 48) + 
    char(1000 / 10 % 10 + 48) + 
    char(1000 % 10 + 48)) ;
```

how can i get same result in MY Sql? i am creating a unique code by using char method?

Comment: You add confusion with your use of constants - your previous question better explains your goal though it had to be dragged out of you with multiple questions. Unfortunately your previous question was closed. Perhaps the better question is why you focus on applying that mysql code to sql server (rather than just writing that logic "better" in tsql).

Comment: @SMor actualy i am using mysql as database here i used constants because i am facing error while implementing same code in my sql special at valued like 99,999,9999 etc ther might be another values also. here i am using constant because i am using count(*) therefore using constant like 1000,99,999 etc because i am not getting same codes as in sql server. i am facing simple concern that i want to generate code A000-A999-B000-B999 AND SO ON.

Answer (score 0):

MySql doesn't accept + as concatanation fpror strings, switch to CONCAT

> ```
> select CONCAT(char(1000 / 1000 % 26 + 65 using utf16) ,
>     char(1000 / 100 % 10 + 48 using utf16) , 
>     char(1000 / 10 % 10 + 48 using utf16) , 
>     char(1000 % 10 + 48 using utf16), 
>     char(9999 using utf16 )) ;
> ```
>
> ```
>  B000✏
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=864249bd86ca58ae044b4c9bf4ba07a7)*

Comment: concat is not providing accurate result: at value of 1000 concate is displaying : instead of 0;

Comment: conact works perfectly, your get the ascii character of the provided number, show a fillde where you get :

Comment: at value of 99,999,9999  i am getting : and how can i convert the same in number?

Comment: You don't explain what you expect see the changed answer and see if UTF16 helps, you further as only you know what you expect, there are more uft characters set that you can experiment with

Comment: i just want to create a sequence of number from A000to Z999 and using numeric value of char i am making unique code in sql server i am getting value perfectly sequenced at value like 99,999,etc but in my sql i am unabe to get those values i want same response in my sql also concate is also not helping either

Comment: that is usually **impossible** in parallel systems, as every system besides autoincrement and uuid **will produces duplicates**, independent of rdms. write a function that will try to find a unused number. Even then my last code will workto get a deterministic result. i guess that the actual character doesn't matter.

Comment: to avoid duplicacy i will use unique entry that is not the issue but i want same alphanumeric sequence. actualy in my table there is not pk column id so i am using count(*) to get the approximate value. I just want a sequence in order from A000-A-999 the thing is that i cant pass A as constant i need value from A to z otherwise i had to make a query at A999 convert A to B something like that?

Comment: actually i while i am facing errors this happening due to char value of single digit e.g select  char(99 / 100 % 10 + 48) = 1 my sql while the value of same char function is 0 in sql server due to that i am getting different valued even on concat i don't know why because 99/100 are getting diffrent values in diffrente databases;

Comment: char uses ascii as default that is why i added the urt16 character set, so tha6t numbers about 255 will not produce an error